# EF Power Tools Beta 2 and Visual Studio 2012 RC

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio-2012, entity-framework-5

The ADO.NET blog at

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2012/04/09/ef-power-tools-beta-2-available.aspx

says:

**Compatibility**

The Power Tools are compatible with Visual Studio 2010 and Entity Framework 4.2 or later.

**You can also install the Power Tools on Visual Studio 11 Beta, but you may receive the error "A constructible type deriving from DbContext could not be found in the selected file."** This is caused by a bug in the Visual Studio 11 unit test tools where an older version of EntityFramework.dll is being loaded. We are working closely with that team to resolve the issue. As a workaround, you can delete the HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0_Config\BindingPaths{BFC24BF4-B994-4757-BCDC-1D5D2768BF29} registry key. Be aware, however, that this will cause the Unit Test commands to stop working. Thank you, early adopters, for your superhuman patience with prerelease software.

**My question is:** 
Does anybody know if this issue is resolved on VS2012 Professional RC? I have a pretty stable installation and don't want to mess up with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is fixed in Visual Studio 2012 RC.